# Removing all the messages from MSMQ

Tags: msmq, message

I have a Nunit test which adds message into MSMQ.
In the teardown of the NUnit i want to remove all the message from the queue.
Is there a direct way to remove all the messages from the queue (some kind of refresh) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there a Purge() method on your queue object that would do the trick?

Edit: Yup - seems to be: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms703966%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: And the .NET method reference is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.messagequeue.purge.aspx